# Bluetooth mouse on windows: Periodically loses connection

Tags: windows, bluetooth

Win10, observed on multiple laptops
Mouse: Microsoft Arc Touch, Microsoft Surface mouse, observed across multiple mice

Everything works great, but periodically (like once an hour, sometimes once every ten or fifteen minutes), the laptop seems to lose connection to the mouse for about five seconds. This happens in multiple locations, at home and away.

How to diagnose and resolve?

Comment: @K7AAY Thanks. I have had the problem all over, in different places.

Comment: Then record the times this happens, and use the logs to see what was going on at those times.

Comment: @K7AAY I have no idea how that would be productive. I would have a list of times, with no idea what to do with that information.

Comment: I guess "use the logs" meant "check entries in Windows event viewer". Did you ever do that when the problem appeared?